# Using multiple callbacks to call functions in order

Tags: jquery

Ok I am going backwards here

I know how deferred works here

```
function strong() {
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    console.log("strong running");
    setTimeout(function() {
      def.resolve("strong");
    }, 2000);
    return def.promise();
}

function stronger(x) {
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    display("Stronger: '" + x + "'");
    setTimeout(function() {
      def.resolve("stronger");
    }, 2000);
    return def.promise();
}

strong().then(stronger);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8njW4/

My question is before deferred was introduced, how was this done using callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would pass the callback as a function argument:

```
function strong(callback) {
    console.log("strong running");
    setTimeout(callback, 2000);
}

function stronger(x, callback) {
    console.log("Stronger: '" + x + "'");
    setTimeout(callback, 2000);
}

strong(function() {
    stronger(3, function() {});
});
```

Comment: can you explain your code. Why are you mentioning callback in the argument as well as in setTimeout. It may be obvious but I new to this.

Comment: The argument is how you pass the callback to the function. Then you call it via `setTimeout`, because you want to wait 2 seconds as in your original code.

Comment: Ok the callback mechanism looks pretty good. Why use deferred at all in this specific case?

Comment: Deferred is more flexible, because it allows the caller to decide whether they want to do something after, instead of making every function contain code to call the callback. Also, notice how much simpler your original code to call `strong` and `stronger` is than mine.